# Property nullity check doesn't work on iteration

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype

In the code below, the `ab.bv` check doesn't work to iterate over `ab.bv`. It works, however, to access elements of `ab.bv`. Has the `if (ab.bv)` check not checked for nullity of `ab.bv`?

```js
type B = {|
    bv: ?B[], 
|}

const c: B => void = n => {}

let ab: B = {bv: []}
if (ab.bv) {
  for (const v2 in ab.bv) { // Error in ab.bv: cannot iterate using a `for...in` statement because array type [1] is not an object, null, or undefined. [invalid-in-rhs]
    c({...ab})
  }
  c({...ab.bv[0]}) // Works
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refinement works, just the error is a bit not clear. Flow is trying to tell you that you should use `for...of` to iterate the array instead of `for...in` (as you'll get the indexes instead of array items):

```
let ab: B = {bv: []}
if (ab.bv) {
  for (const v2 of ab.bv) { // Works
    c(v2)
  }
  c({...ab.bv[0]}) // Works
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AIVALygDeAPoqJaAEYBuAXKAPy4DaAugDSiKkC+yAMawAdgGcUoQY3wEAfKFqwAlgBNCoEYQXEBiaFkkBDajI3E6jDgOWRQAChMA6OgEoSFUJFgAnB8PFJWgAmUFg7ZzcSUBBQAHVfAGsxT0pBexDXTwE0+2InAsjaVgAGdj53WISfZMQ+IA)